# Registered as a Ltd company but not traded yet; government threatening me for not filing taxes

Tags: united-kingdom, liability

I registered myself as a Ltd company a year ago with the UK government to ready myself for working freelance as a web developer. Since then I have been involved in other projects (mostly voluntary, some conventionally paid employment, on which I paid taxes) and have not done any freelance/company work whatsoever.

Now I'm getting bills from the UK government for ever escalating amounts (they are saying £1300 last letter I got) for not filing taxes for a company that has not traded at all in any meaningful sense of the word (have paid out for some artworks and server rental, but never actually charged for any services).

What can I do about this? I don't have £13 spare cash, let alone £1300. Is there anything I can do to stop the government charging me money I do not have for tax returns it would have made no sense to file and the forms for which I don't understand anyway?

I already paid them £15 to register the company with Companies House and they have done literally nothing for me in return, so I really don't see how they can be wanting £1300 as a result of my not trading whatsoever.

Comment: I'm not in UK, but I believe NZ law is similar.   Can you confirm if these bills were to you, or to your company, and what exactly they were for ?  If its the company, you can either wind up the company, or simply let it fall off the companies office for not filing a return for a few years.  My guess that these charges are for default assessments because you failed to fill out returns/paperwork.     The salient point, is YOU ARE NOT THE COMPANY - you are the director of the company.  You are unlikely to be personally liable for the debt.

Comment: £1300 is a fine for not filing your taxes. For a start, file your taxes. Say you have 0 income and 0 expenses and 0 whatever else, they will be fine with that - you'll be surprised how many companies don't trade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The £1,300 demand is *to get you moving* to do something. You started a company. You are a company director. You get letters. You need to read the letters and do what you are asked to do. Go through the letters that you received, find a phone number, and call HMRC and talk to a living person there.

As long as they don't hear from you they assume and must assume that you are running a company that makes lots of money and doesn't pay its taxes. What else are they supposed to think? Call them, talk to them, and they will sort it out.

Here's an important thing: Whoever you talk to, they can be as helpful or as unhelpful as they want, so you must make them want to help you. Shouting and threatening will make them very unhelpful. Acting as the poor man who has no idea what he is doing will make them want to get you out of the system in the cheapest possible way.

BTW. You are saying they have done literally nothing for you in return of your £15 registration? They did a lot. They gave you an entry in the Company House database, protecting your name, and letting anyone find your business. They sent you reminder letters to do your taxes etc. and apparently more than one. They gave you the information that you need to open a business bank account, and so on.

Comment: I filled in their forms now (the process has changed so today I was finally able to). I'm sure they would have made sense to other people. I did my best. I hope they leave me alone for a while. If I was making money I wouldn't care. I just write computer code and try to make something of myself.

Comment: Amy, get on the phone and talk to someone in person. I'll change that: Amy, get on the bloody phone and talk to someone in person.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. The first guy I got through to sounded flustered and said he'd need to transfer me departments. Then I got transferred, started to explain the situation -- the phone beeped, then the line went dead. I was about to call back when I got an inexplicable feeling I should try online again. I did so and found there was a new process in place which enabled me to verify my identity with a passport, driver's license, debit card and a bunch of questions. I answered those and then it *finally* actually let me file my taxes, which I did as best I could. I'm waiting on a response now.

Answer (score 0):

Your company is required to lodge an annual tax return. If it doesn't, it will be fined. These charges are the fines. Talk to your accountant.

Comment: I don't have an accountant. I have no money. I work part time in a factory, which barely covers my bills.

Comment: @DaleM is probably correct - but check carefully - you will probably find its THE COMPANY that owes the money not you.   You might want to write a letter to the companies office telling them you are ceasing to be a director of the company and they can do with the company as they will.  If its anything like New Zealand (and I asked the question as it happens)  it will throw a cat among the pigeons and they won't like it - but I'm pretty sure you can't be forced to continue as a directorthat would be an act of slavery !  They will probably land up removing the company eventually.

Comment: @davidgo interestingly, I just tried to file for the company online, but they have my old address and when I try to update it they want to mail a security code to the old address in order to do so!! Yet they appear to have had no problem updating the address for the purposes of billing. It seems to make sense for them to keep the debt on record for when the company does make money (no problem paying my dues) and writing it down as a government asset until then, but putting in place a system that makes it more difficult to file taxes than to bill people for not doing so... seems a little sly.

Comment: Please don't take offence, but (if you arn't) you should very, very seriously consider letting the company fall off the register - and make sure you are in a financial position to employ [least part time] an accountant or advisor who can help you navigate the tax system and rules around companies.    You will probably find one is an address for service and the other a billing address - its entirely reasonable that these could be different as they serve different purposes.  If the UK companies office is anything like the NZ one, give them a call to straighten out the address.

Comment: "I work part time in q factory" - no, you don't, you are a company director which carries serious legal obligations.

Comment: @DaleM - that is a bit harsh. In my experience very few people who start there own businesses know what it actually means - I certainly didnt fot the first 5 years I ran my business. This person is clearly unaware of the obligations and meaning of being a director - and this does not make them evil or stupid - Ive seen smart enough people make the same mistake.

Comment: @davidgo it doesn't make them evil - it does make them stupid - anyone who accepts a legal obligation without understanding what it means is stupid in my book.

Comment: @DaleM - Law is not (in my experience anyway - in 2 countries) taught in schools - and when I formed my companies, no one advised me that I needed to be aware of the companies act, have familiarity with tax laws or even that a company is not truly mine, even when I am sole director and shareholder.  On the other hand, there is pressure to "trade as a company" to seem legitimate - so, although wrong, someone thinking "Ok, I'll pay $15 and get a company" is not stupid, its just naive.

Comment: @davidgo you can call it naive if it makes you feel better. Naive is just stupid with a "sucker" sticker as well. Certainly in Australia you are taught in school not to sign something unless you fully understand it. That may not be "law" but it will keep you out of 99.9% of legal difficulties.